# How to differentiate using web3.py functions from a smart contract based on type/visibility?

Tags: python, web3py

I'm connecting to a smart contract with web3.py.

I am the contract owner connecting with the same address which deployed the contract.

I can print all functions, but I would like to separate each function based on their type and visibility, like read only or modify state, and visibility like: internal, external, public, etc.

Is there a way to do that with the web3.py library or any other library?

Here is my code:

```
# CONNECT TO CHAIN WITH WEB3
url = 'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/e30d3bc3dfba4f92949b789dc797d82e'
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(url))

# CONNECT TO SMART CONTRACT
address = address_ABI.address                   # Importing from other file for more readability
abi = json.loads(address_ABI.abi)               # Importing from other file for more readability
contract = w3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi)

# ACCOUNTS:
account_0 = wallets.account_0                   # Importing from other file for more readability
private_key_0 = wallets.private_key_0           # Importing from other file for more readability

# LIST ALL CONTRACT FUNCTIONS
contract_functions = contract.all_functions()   # Returns a list with all functions
print(len(contract_functions))                  # Print number of functions
for function in contract_functions:             # Print function one by one
    print(function)
```

How do I print functions by different type and visibility? Like public, payable, read only, internal, external, etc?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, not the most elegant, but working:

You can extract from the contract.abi all the elements and then call anything you want from the dictionary with the following: 'stateMutability'. this will return you the state, like: pure, view, non-payable, etc.
Here is a sample code:

```
for element in contract.abi:
    if element['type'] == 'function':
        print(element['name'], element['stateMutability'])
    else:
        pass
```

You can also extract other types, like "event' instead of 'function'. Hope this helps.